# Convert decimal to balanced Heptavintimal

Tags: c++, radix, base-conversion, ternary-representation

I'm trying to make a function to convert decimal to balanced Heptavintimal (0123456789ABCDEFGHKMNPRTVXZ)
where 0 represent -13, D : 0 and Z 13

I have tried this but some cases are not working properly:

```
static const std::string HEPT_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHKMNPRTVXZ";

std::string heptEnc(int value){
    std::string result = "";

    do {
        int pos = value % 27;
        result = std::string(HEPT_CHARS[(pos + 13)%27] + result);
        value = value / 27;
    } while (value != 0);

    return result;
}
```

Here is what I get in this example -14, -15, 14, 15 isn't working

```
call(x) - expect: result
heptEnc(-9841) - 000: 000
heptEnc(-15) - CX: 
heptEnc(-14) - CZ: 
heptEnc(-13) - 0: 0
heptEnc(-1) - C: C
heptEnc(0) - D: D
heptEnc(1) - E: E
heptEnc(13) - Z: Z
heptEnc(14) - E0: 0
heptEnc(15) - E1: 1
heptEnc(9841) - ZZZ: ZZZ
```

Comment: What are you supposed to get for those values? Have you tried to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: the expected value is before `:` so yes I expect E0, but I only get 0, I edited the post to specify my synthax

Comment: The algorithm can't be right. `(-15) % 27 == -15`. and then you access `HEPT_CHARS` at a negative offset.

Comment: `value = value / 27;` cannot be correct, if `value == 14`, you have to get 2 digits, but the loop will break after the first digit.

Comment: @mchjust figure out, trying to get around this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got it working, here is the code:

```
static const std::string HEPT_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHKMNPRTVXZ";

inline int modulo(int a, int b) 
{
    const int result = a % b;
    return result >= 0 ? result : result + b;
}

std::string heptEnc(int value)
{
    std::string result = "";

    do {
        int pos = value%27;
        result = std::string(HEPT_CHARS[modulo(pos + 13,27)] + result);
        value = (value+pos) / 27;
    } while (value != 0);

    return result;
}
```

Apparently a mix of mathematical modulo, C++ modulo and modifying the way you update your value did the trick.

Comment: indeed mathimatical trick, and since I doind calculation and paper, so my calculator use Math modulo and not c++ modulo

anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using mod (`%`) incorrectly.  It's difficult/complicated to know what a `signed int` will initially be set to. So try this instead:

```
unsigned int uvalue = std::abs(value);
unsigned int upos = uvalue % 27;
int pos = static_cast<int>(upos) - 13;
```

Of course you'll have to deal with the sign of your conversion separately:

```
int sign = value >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: in fact it's not a problem of sign. more a problem around `value = value / 27;` the problem is the balanced system, since 0 represet -13 and Z +13 so E0 ca be read as 27 + -13 so it's 14